# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'path_to_dir.json'

Tags: python, file-not-found

I am trying to code for a saving and loading function for a particular game however, I keep being presented with the `FileNotFoundError` message.

```
def save_file():
    save_progress = input("Would you like to save you current progress? (Y/N):")
    if save_progress == 'Y':
        save_name = input("savename:")
        path = 'path_to_dir.json'.format(save_name)
        data = {
        'name': save_name
        }
        with open(path, 'w+') as f:
            json.dump(data,f)
        if save_progress == 'N':
            print("That fine maybe next time!")

def load_file():
    load_name = save_name
    path_two = 'path_to_dir.json'.format(load_name)
    with open(path_two, 'r') as f:
        j = json.load(f)
        name = str(j['name'])
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Please give an example run and output.

Comment: What do you do here: `path = 'path_to_dir.json'.format(save_name)`. There is no placeholder in the string, so `format` does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to use following line:

```
path = 'path_to_dir.json'.format(save_name)
```

in a way like this

```
path = 'path_to_dir/{}.json'.format(save_name)
```

Maybe `path_to_dir` should be the filename.

You might want to look into the following way to work with strings as it might feel more natural.

```
path = f'path_to_dir/{save_name}.json'
```

Answer (score 0):

he problem is with this part of your code:

```
if save_progress == 'Y':
    save_name = input("savename:")
    path = 'path_to_dir.json'.format(save_name)
```

You've only created `path_to_dir` *if* the user inputs `Y`.

If the user doesn't input `Y`, you didn't do anything to stop this part of the code from running:

```
path_two = 'path_to_dir.json'.format(load_name)
```

causing the `FileNotFoundError`.

Use an `if` statement to determine whether the program should run the `load_file` function, depending on whether a file has been created:

```
import json

def save_file():
    save_progress = input("Would you like to save you current progress? (Y/N): ")
    if save_progress == 'Y':
        save_name = input("savename: ")
        path = f'{save_name}.json'
        data = {'name': save_name}
        with open(path, 'w+') as f:
            json.dump(data,f)
        return save_name
    if save_progress == 'N':
        print("That fine maybe next time!")

def load_file(save_name):
    load_name = save_name
    path_two = f'{save_name}.json'
    with open(path_two, 'r') as f:
        j = json.load(f)
        name = j['name']

save_name = save_file()
if save_name:
    load_file()
```

Comment: So how would I go about rewording the function?

Comment: The code keeps bringing back an error saying TypeError: save_file() missing 1 required positional argument: 
'save_name'

Comment: @Soulstealer123 Oh, I'm very sorry! Turns out `def save_file(save_name):` should be just `def save_file():`.